# Fancyfoot only applied on the last page

Tags: texstudio, fancyhdr

I'm trying to move my page numbers to the right. Here is the code of the whole document:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{pics/}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\title{
    ...
}
\author{
    ...
    
}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    \chapter*{Abstract}
    ...
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \input{chapters/ch1}
\end{document}
```

However, page number is only moved on the last page of the document. *Introduction* only contains a couple of sections and doesn't apply any styles. Neither of dotted out fragments contain any commands.

Why do the page numbers remain at the center of the page?

Comment: \chapter and \tableofcontents switch from fancy to plain (one page each).  You can reset plain using \fancypagestyle{plain}{...}.  See pages 10-11.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yep, it works. Please, post it as an answer, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\pagestyle{plain}` fixed, one might as well use it for every page.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{pics/}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyfoot{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\title{
    ...
}
\author{
    ...
    
}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    \chapter*{Abstract}
    ...
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    %\input{chapters/ch1}
\end{document}
```